Preservative-treated posts in post frame construction: code interpretation
I am designing and building my own post-frame shop building and I need help with interpretation of the code. Specifically, my posts are connected to an engineered concrete foundation with wet-set Sturdi Wall brackets. In my application, the underside of the bracket rests on the top of the concrete, so the posts rest above the concrete by the thickness of the bracket (around 1/4 inch). The concrete foundation surface is around 4 inches above grade. The grade was brought up from natural grade with 3/4-inch road base. My question is, how should I interpret the "and" statement in the code (see below) to determine if I need treated or untreated posts?
Specifically, in Section "R317.1 Location required.", item 2, of the 2021 International Residential Code it states:

Wood framing members, including columns, that rest directly on concrete or masonry exterior foundation walls and are less than 8 inches (203 mm) from the exposed ground.

The word "directly" was specifically added to this standard to exempt columns resting on impermeable barriers. This much is true from the videos included with the premium subscription to the standards. In these videos, a Simpson Strong Tie representative specifically argues for adding the word "directly" to allow exceptions when using structural post brackets.
However, I am still left confused as to how I should interpret the "and" statement in the code. I am a software engineer by trade, so, to me, an and statement is a strict, well defined thing. Specifically, the statement a and b yields true if and only if both a and b are true. With this context in mind, both of the following need to be true in order to require treated wood.

Wood rests directly on concrete.
Wood is within 8 inches of exposed ground.

For me, 1. is false and 2., with a dirt floor, is true. One is false, and therefore I do not need preservative-treated posts. If the statement was an or statement instead, it would be different. In software engineering, either a or b can be true for the statement a or b to return true. However, the code does not say "or", it says "and". Can anyone help with this interpretation? Am I getting too into the weeds here?
Note that the 2021 IBC, section "2304.12.2.2 Posts or columns." provides explicit guidance by stating:

Exception: Posts or columns that meet all of the following:
1.Are not exposed to the weather, or are protected by a roof, eave, overhang, or other covering if exposed to the weather.
2.Are supported by concrete piers or metal pedestals projected not less than 1 inch (25 mm) above the slab or deck and are separated from
the concrete pier by an impervious moisture barrier.
3.Are located not less than 8 inches (203 mm) above exposed earth.

In this case, I would need preservative-treated posts. I have a call into the county, and I'll likely just use treated posts to be safe, but I'd still like to hear what the community has to say about this stuff. To me, when interpreting specific rules like this, the difference between "or" and "and" is everything.

What matters here is what your local authority thinks, not what we think…

Most code is the minimum required.  There are usually no exceptions to going above code within reason.  Using 8 or 6 gauge wire on a 15 amp breaker might not fit, but 12 or 10 will(but costs more).

@crip659 In my opinion, untreated wood is the better choice here (if I can get away with it). My admittedly limited experience with pressure treated wood has seen it warped and twisted beyond recognition within a couple months.

@JonCuster yes, I agree, but I guess I was looking for advice on how to generally read the code. Does things like this really matter? I can't call the county and wait for a response every time I encounter an "and" in the code.

I have PT treated wood from the 90s(might be ban now), with no warping/twisting.  Two small decks and a picnic table, both as straight when built and no rot.

Agree that the AHJ will have the final word, but any engineering docs you can get from the base mfr might help. Plus, if those posts are built up from multiple 2x, it'll be pretty easy to force them straight.
